# How to add additional options when buying a product?

Tags: magento2, product-page

Please tell me how you can implement this

[image]

that at the time of purchase of the product the customer could choose additional products.

Comment: I think that is custom options, not any products.

Comment: Use Magento 2 custom option to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use custom options for this kind of setup.

You can go through https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/settings-advanced-custom-options.html to learn about custom options.